# Where can I find more information on refugees living in Poland?

Tags: data-sources, refugees, poland

I want to know the refugee data of Poland since its accession to the EU. For example:

1. When did the refugees come to Poland?
2. What were their countries of origin?
3. How many of them came?
4. What are their ethnic compositions?
5. What are their religious compositions?

Where can I find this data?

Comment: A quick Google search turns up most of this and there is [a decent article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refugees_in_Poland). Please do some preliminary research and edit your question to ask one specific question if there is something you still can't find.